# Connecting Qlikview to Azure Data Lake Store Gen 1

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, qlikview, qliksense

I am working on a new requirement and need to connect Qliksense and Qlikview to Azure Data Lake Store Gen 1.  I  search a lot about it but didn't find any useful information to claim the connectivity betweem Qlik and Microsoft Azure Data lake.

Answer (score 0):

We are deploying Qlikview to to Azure and received the following assistance from Microsoft so hopefully it leads you in the correct direction:

- https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2018/Subsystems/PlanningQlikSenseDeployments/Content/Sense_Deployment/Azure-architecture.htm

Azure deployment
In a Microsoft Azure deployment, you install Qlik Sense Enterprise on a Azure cloud infrastructure that is flexible, high performance, and is quick to set up.

Deploying Qlik Sense Enterprise on Azure will enable you to quickly add new applications in a simple, and scalable manner. You can do this with a basic knowledge of Azure security and scalability options but without the need to follow complex on-premise installation and configuration procedures. Using Azure will enable you to get your Qlik Sense infrastructure up and running in fraction of the time required for an on-premise deployment, and will enable you to scale your deployment quickly and easily, regardless of unexpected changes in demand.

You can deploy Qlik Sense to Azure manually, or you can use an Virtual Hard Disk (VHD) available in the Azure Marketplace that includes Qlik Sense preinstalled. However, predefined images do not include a file share, so can only support single node Qlik Sense deployments.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the comment, but my requirement here is little different then what you had explained, I want my qlik reports to take the data stored in Azure Data Lake. The above information is related to how to deploy qlik in Azure. Also the link you attached doesn't mention explicitly if we can connect Azure Data Lake and qlik.